# Not able to include 2 controller.js files on single html page. Getting Error- Argument {mycontroller} is not a function, got undefined

Tags: html, angularjs

I am  new to angular, and stuck with nested angular controllers. I have kept all the controllers in separate .js files.

The main controller on my problem (html)page must nest another controller 'UploadController' to upload images.

I don't want to keep the main controller and UploadController in same file because the Uploadcontroller will be used at other pages also.

// app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('myApp', []);    

})();
```

//  MainController.js

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http)
    {
    // my code      
    }]);

  }());
```

// UploadController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngMessages"]);
    app.controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http)
    {

    // Code

    }]);

}());
```

// page.html

```
<title>
 <script src="/cdn/scripts/angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/cdn/scripts/angular/controller/maincontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="/cdn/scripts/angular/controller/uploadcontroller.js"></script>   

</title

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <div ng-controller="UploadController">

      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

This is the error I am getting while running the Code.

**Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', []);
})();
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        // my code      
        $scope.name = "main controller";
    }]);
}());
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        // Code
        $scope.name = "edit controller";
    }]);
}());
```

```html
<script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    
<body ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
     <div ng-controller="EditController">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your app dependencies only once since you are not using any sub-modules.

This is what should be done:

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);    

})();
```

Main Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

      var app = angular.module('myApp');
     app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http)
    {
    // my code      
    }]);

  }());
```

Upload controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http)
    {

    // Code

    }]);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the [] in UploadController and it worked.
Thanks all for answering.